# How to set environment before running custom action?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, cpack

I'm using WIX toolset to build up Windows installer package. The package includes a main software, a tool executable and some 3rd party dependencies.

For some reason I wish to run the tool executable during the installation process, which needs some  environment variables to be set in the installation procedure.

I'm using WiX custom action to execute the tool executable, but found the environment variables set in the install procedure still can't be recognized by the tool executable.

How could I move the environment variable setting before the custom action?